# DAX: Days between two days with restrictions (VAR?)

Tags: dax

I want to make a simple calculation column with days between two dates, however the data is messy and I want to exclude when blanks or mismatching dates occur.

[START DATE]
[END DATE]

My idea is a DATEDIFF with a VAR helping to clean out the following

[START DATE] if blank then blank
[END DATE] if blank then blank
DATEdiff return must be equal or above zero

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    COUNTROWS(DATESBETWEEN(<dates>, <start_date>, <end_date>))
```